# What quantity should be used in the Stefan-Boltzmann Law?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I am currently looking into the Stefan-Boltzmann Law, and I am constantly seeing different quantities used. In some books I see "Intensity" and in others I see "Radiance", "Energy desnity" or "Radiancy". Could anyone help me understand why different terms are used and what they mean? Thank you.

Comment: this talks about units https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law . Take a look at the units on "The constant of proportionality σ, called the Stefan–Boltzmann constant" which should help

Answer (score 0):

Radiant energy per unit time or intensity can be used. It has the same meaning.

Comment: Please, try to address the full question. Which contains also the "why different terms are used? "  part.